# Xcode label text from date picked

Tags: ios, xcode, calendar, label

I have a calendar view that displays the days of the month, and I would like to put the output into my label but am unable to. I can NSLog it but not transfer it into a label. Here is my code:

```
- (void)calendarView:(DSLCalendarView *)calendarView didSelectRange:(DSLCalendarRange *)range {
    if (range != nil) {
        NSLog( @"%ld/%ld", (long)range.startDay.month, (long)range.endDay.day);
        NSString *datechosen = ( @"%ld/%ld", range.startDay.month,range.endDay.day);
        DatePicked.text = datechosen;

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you declared your label ? Did you connected the outlet ?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
if(DatePicked)
{
    DatePicked.text = datechosen;
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"hey look, DatePicked is not connected to an IBOutlet");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DatePicked.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%ld/%ld",(long)range.startDay.mont, (long)range.endDay.day];
```

Pleaes read [Formatting String Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html).